# Bootstrap 3x3 grid with Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am making an Ionic 3 by 3 even grid that fit to the screen without scrolling horizontally and vertically. I want to use bootstrap's div class.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="/img/pic.jpg></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="/img/pic.jpg></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="/img/pic.jpg></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can divide the column into three sections. I don't know how to control the rows? I only want 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

col-xs is only for Extra Small screens (<768px).
You can read more about Grid options here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

You can simply change your div classes into the "col-lg-4" and you will be good I think, if your screen is bigger than 1200 px.

There is so many ways to control these divs.

1. .container-fluid .row div
2. .col-xs-4
3. You can add another class like "mydiv" and you will be able to control it with .mydiv selector in CSS.

There is alot more ways to control these divs, so do some research, read the bootstrap website and you will be good :)